# Perfecting a curve in logo, Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I'm rather new to Illustrator, and I'm currently designing a logo.

Just refining it at the moment, checking all the measurements etc...

But I'm wondering what's the best way to tackle this curve:[image]

As you can see it's nowhere near perfect. I'm mainly focusing on the curve on the inside. Then I can adjust the outside by measuring.

I can't seem to find an accurate way of correcting this curve.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Keep the number of anchors you place to a minimum, make sure you have placed plenty of guides, and constrain the angle of the Bézier handles vertically by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> after you begin clicking and dragging with the Pen tool.

[image]

Comment: Or use gridsnap, or numeric input ;)

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to create things like this is to utilize existing rudimentary options.

Draw a Rounded Rectangle using the **Rounded Rectangle Tool**. While dragging tap the `Up Arrow` until the sides are completely rounded.

Set the shape to have a *very* thick stroke. If you know they rectangles you need are 20px in height (you can check by selecting one and looking at the Control bar across the top of the screen), set the stroke to 20px, etc. to match the height of the existing rectangles.

Choose `Object > Expand` - results in a shape rather than a stroke.

Delete the left side anchor points.

Join the anchors at the resulting open ends and adjust the straight portion lengths.

[image]

Then connect with other, existing artwork.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've used your technique on other parts of my logo. Thanks ever so much.